# Firefox ignoring min-height in CSS when using calc or percentage

Tags: html, css

I currently have a [website](http://msuclarinet.greene.tech) where I'd like the main body portion of the page and footer (below the header image and navigation bar) to always take up the available view space, but to expand below this if there's more content. I've been setting `min-height` of my container of class mainbody to a `calc()` function. The HTML and CSS have been tested and behave correctly in Safari and Chromium, however it fails to behave as intended on Firefox. The problem is most apparent on the Alumni page, which has no content at the moment, and also occurs on the Media page on a large enough screen . Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

100% height means 100% of the height of the content. To be honest, I don't know why it works in chromium and not in firefox.

What you need is 100% of the viewport. There are cool `vw` and `vh` units for that. ([See availability.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)).

If you change `min-height` to `min-height: calc(100vh - 268px) !important;`, it will work.

If you want old style solution, you can google `100% height css`, e.g. [enter link description here](http://www.mattboldt.com/css-100-percent-height/)

P.S.: Also [fix your CSS](http://CSS%20https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmsuclarinet.greene.tech%2Fcss%2Fstyle.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en).